# How to protect button in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a button in a spreadsheet document which is clearing data in it. Unfortunately at the moment every user can press the button. Is there a way to protect the button so only specific users can press it.

Comment: You could improve the quality of your questions by sharing a brief description of your search/research efforts. It's worth to note that some members of this community receive better questions that include code that those which didn't. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply - you can't protect a button, however, if this is in relation to the answer I gave in the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186206/how-to-create-a-button-which-clears-data-in-spreadsheets) that you posted, I would place the button on your private template sheet that the user doesn't see.

Or you could use a custom menu instead of the button.

This script will create a custom menu if the active user matches the if condition.

```
function onOpen(){

 var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   if(user == '--your email address here--'){   
     ui.createMenu('Custom Functions')
       .addItem('Clear sheet', 'myFunction')       
       .addToUi();
  }
}
```

Comment: getActiveUser().getEmail() could return blank. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getemail

Comment: Ah yes, if the script is authorized it should return the email and for all other users it won't return and won't create the menu. They can of course always access it through the script editor but I don't think that is a concern in this instance.

Comment: Fantastic thanks a ton and sorry for the newbish questions!

Comment: Everybody has to ask the newbish questions sometime! It was me asking them a year or 2 ago.