# Protect the button from deleting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to protect the button from deleting. This button works with a submitData() script. The users must be able to press it, but not to delete. If I protect the whole sheet then the users can't use this button at all. But when it is not protected, everybody can delete it easily (right button of the mouse, Delete).

[image]
Sil = Delete

I have found some more or less similar questions about created buttons in Google Sheets, for ex.: [How to protect button in google spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190108/how-to-protect-button-in-google-spreadsheets). This question was asked more than 2 years ago, but the answer in general was "No". My goal is a bit different: I want to switch off the option of deleting of the button from all the users except me (the author of the sheet). Is it possible today?

Comment: What's your question?  What do you want us to help you with?

Comment: My question is if it is possible to protect it from deleting. I have found some more or less similar questions about created buttons in Google Sheets, for ex.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190108/how-to-protect-button-in-google-spreadsheets. This question was asked more than 2 years ago, but the answer in general was "No". My goal is a bit different: I want to switch off the option of deleting of the button from all the users except me (the author of the sheet). Is it possible today?

Comment: Please add those detail to your question.

Comment: Does a custom menu not work for your purposes?

Comment: @iansedano, no, I can't use a custom menu, because I need this script, which is connected to the button, to work with one click. It is very important, because the user has limited time when working with this form.

Comment: How complex is the sheet with the form? Is a form with an `onSubmit` trigger something you have looked at? Also, if you really need complete control, then maybe a WebApp will be the way to go. Because there is no way currently to protect a button